# Python requests.get outputs a 400 Bad Request error file

Tags: python, excel, get, python-requests

i'm trying to create a script to download a test excel (.xlsx) file. The script does output a 'test'.xlsx file, but it contains the following error message instead of the actual file contents.

**Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.***

I did manage to download the test file using urllib, however would like to use requests instead as I require authentication for my actual use case. Here's the code i used, do let me know what's wrong, thanks!

```
import requests
dls = "http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/excel-files/fibonacci-sequence.xlsx"
resp = requests.get(dls)

output = open('test.xlsx', 'wb')
output.write(resp.content)
output.close()
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code snippet. this should work as intended. it's probably a problem at the server side. try it with an excel file from a different host.

Comment: yes, I get 200 (success code) from the server.
try another one time later

Comment: Well i tried it with another file which requires authentication, and I face the same problem. However, I am running the script within my work environment. Not sure if that could be the reason? I have used urllib to download the exact same file, and was able to, not sure why requests doesnt work.